# Computing The Following Variance.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

$$\hat\theta_g=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{e^2}{2}e^{-2X_i}$$

where the $X_i$ are an iid sample from a pdf.

Show that $$Var(\hat\theta_g)=\frac{1}{n}Var(\frac{e^2}{2}e^{-2X_1})$$

#### My attempt:

$$Var(\hat\theta_g)=Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{e^2}{2}e^{-2X_i})$$

Since $X_i$ are an iid sample

$$Var(\hat\theta_g)=Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{e^2}{2}e^{-2X_1})$$

$$Var(\hat\theta_g)=Var(\frac{1}{n}n\frac{e^2}{2}e^{-2X_1})$$

$$Var(\hat\theta_g)=Var(\frac{e^2}{2}e^{-2X_1})$$

But the answer is:

$$Var(\hat\theta_g)=\frac{1}{n}Var(\frac{e^2}{2}e^{-2X_1})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(\xi_i)$ is i.i.d., then $\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\xi_i\right)=\frac1n\mathrm{Var}\left(\xi_1\right)$, not $\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac1nn\xi_1\right)$. The rest of your computations is kosher.

Recall that, for every scalar $a$, $\mathrm{Var}\left(a\xi\right)=a^2\mathrm{Var}\left(\xi\right)$ and that, for every independent $\xi$ and $\eta$, $\mathrm{Var}\left(\xi+\eta\right)=\mathrm{Var}\left(\xi\right)+\mathrm{Var}\left(\eta\right)$.

In your setting, choose $\xi_i=\frac12\mathrm e^2\mathrm e^{-2X_i}$ for every $i$, apply $\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\xi_i\right)=\frac1{n^2}\mathrm{Var}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\xi_i\right)$, then $\mathrm{Var}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\xi_i\right)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Var}\left(\xi_i\right)$ because the random variables $(\xi_i)$ are independent, and finally $\mathrm{Var}\left(\xi_i\right)=\mathrm{Var}\left(\xi_1\right)$ for every $i$ because the random variables $(\xi_i)$ are identically distributed.

Comment: Where is the difference between $Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i)$ and $Var(a\xi)$?

Comment: ?? Please explain.

Comment: That is, if $Var(a\xi)=a^2 Var(\xi) $ , then why not $Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i)=\frac{1}{n^2}Var(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i)$?

Where is the difference between $a$ and $n$. You specified $a$ is a scalar , then what is $n$ actually?  as far i know $n=$sample size but still a constant. I read somewhere they specified $a$ as constant in $Var(a\xi)$.

Comment: "why not..." Indeed, why not? Where do you see that I say this is not true? Or that $n$ is not a constant? Please read.

Comment: How  $Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\xi_i)=\frac{1}{n}Var(\xi_1)$?Is it a property when $\xi_i$'s are iid sample?

Comment: OK, here is a suggestion: stop everything else you are doing and READ SLOWLY this answer. The last paragraph explains EXACTLY what you are asking...